# Mysql Query to find free employees

Tags: mysql

Help me to write mysql query to list only employees who are free ( employees currently without assigned task)

task table sample data

```
   emp_id   task_start_date      task_compeletion_date  task_name
     872    2014-06-03 17:14:44  2014-06-04 17:14:46    task1
     873    2014-07-12 19:02:00  2014-07-13 00:25:00    task2
     872    2014-12-03 13:09:08  2014-12-30 12:54:15    task7
     874    2014-12-10 07:29:53  NULL                   task3
```

emp table sample data

```
   emp_id   first_name          last_name   
     872    John            David
     873    Suresh          Kumar
     874    Peter           Nail
     875    Zio             Xing
```

I created this query

```
select * from emp where emp_id not in ( select emp_id from task) union   select emp.* from emp emp, task task where emp.emp_id = task.emp_id and (task.task_compeletion_date is not null or task.task_compeletion_date<now())  ;
```

but it does not return the required list

Comment: is it that `task_compeletion_date` is NUll that means emplyee is free?

Comment: So it's only ever one employee per task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with a `IS NULL` condition:

```
SELECT emp.* 
FROM emp LEFT JOIN
task on emp.emp_id=task.emp_id
WHERE task.task_start_date IS NULL
```

**Explanation:**

This query will fetch all employee whose id are not in task table.

**Result:**

```
EMP_ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
875     Zio         Xing
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f58091/2).

**EDIT:**

For employees who are free:

```
SELECT emp.* 
FROM emp LEFT JOIN
task on emp.emp_id=task.emp_id
WHERE task.task_start_date IS NULL
      OR (task.task_compeletion_date IS NOT NULL
          AND task.emp_id NOT IN (SELECT emp_id from task where task_compeletion_date>CURDATE()))
GROUP BY emp.emp_id,emp.first_name,emp.last_name
```

See [**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f58091/28).

Comment: free employee means that at the current datetime is not assigned to task

Comment: @techbrainless: You mean task table may contain free employees?

Comment: free employee means that at the current datetime is not assigned to task which means that an employee can be free in one of the following conditions : 1. employee exists in emp table but does not exist in task table 2. emp exists in both emp and task table with NULL task_compeletion_date 3. emp exists in both emp and task table with future task_compeletion_date

Comment: @techbrainless: What will be the output with this sample data?

Comment: @techbrainless: See the edit in my answer. It will get you all the employees who are free (employees who have completed their tasks + employee who are not in the task table itself).

Comment: the output should list details of employees with emp_id 873 and 875

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66568/discussion-between-raging-bull-and-techbrainless).

Comment: 872 has a task with task_compeletion_date in the future which means thats currently he is assigned to task.

Comment: I still don't understand what these 2 queries can't be joined in 1 as I did!

Comment: @CodeBird: Updated my answer. Your answer will result [**this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f58091/29). It selects Peter also. That is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

euh I am not sure, but I think this will do:

```
SELECT * from emp WHERE emp_id NOT IN 
(
  SELECT emp_id FROM task 
  WHERE task_compeletion_date>NOW()
)
```

[**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50a7f/14)

Comment: free employee means that at the current datetime is not assigned to task which means that an employee can be free in one of the following conditions : 1. employee exists in emp table but does not exist in task table 2. emp exists in both emp and task table with NULL task_compeletion_date 3. emp exists in both emp and task table with future task_compeletion_date

Answer (score 0):

Based on @CodeBird query (withoug using union)  , the query can be simplified as the following

```
select * from emp where emp_id not in (select emp_id from tasksample where task_compeletion_date>now() or task_compeletion_date is NULL );
```

Thanks CodeBird. Your simple query helped me too to add another condition to get the required answer.